# Phabricator issue with Arc

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

```
arc diff
Linting...
No lint engine configured for this project.
Running unit tests...
No unit test engine is configured for this project.

Exception:
ERR-CONDUIT-CALL: API Method "differential.creatediff" does not define these parameters: 'arcanistProject'.
(Run with --trace for a full exception trace.)
```

Anyone experienced with phabricator code review tool, the latest document says, we don't need to put any project_id in .arcconfig, but still get exceptions for project id not specified. After adding the project_id, I am getting the above exception and no where i can fine what is wrong or what am i missing.

Comment: Have you solved the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

`arcanistProject` doesn't exist at HEAD. Maybe your client is out of date?